# When passing an array in a session variable from 1 page to another the array is lost

Tags: php, arrays, session

Firstly, I have searched the internet for an answer. I have found a number that appear to solve an identical problem but none of them work. Perhaps I am missing something simple. I hope you can help.

I have a list of persons on an html page from which I can flag any number using the check boxes. This produces an array with which I want to pass the member ids, for processing, to the next page using a session variable. The array is created ok on the first page and stored in the session variable. I have put in two "foreach" statements, as tests, to prove this. When I try to access the array in the second page the array no longer exists.

All the code is on the pages before the 'html' tags.

The code for the page is:-

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    if(!empty($_POST['players'])){           
        $playerArray = $_POST['players'];
        $_SESSION['playerid'] = $playerArray;

        //Test 1
        foreach($playerArray as $memberId){
            echo "Test 1 - Member id - " . $memberId . "<br />";
        }
        //Test2
        foreach($_SESSION['playerid'] as $memberId){
            echo "Test 2- Member id - " . $memberId . "<br />";
        }
    }           
}
?>
```

The code for the 2nd page is:-

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['playerid'])){
    $player = $_SESSION['playerid'];
    echo "playerId array exists";
    //test if it works
    foreach($player as $memberId)
    {
        echo "Member id - " . $memberId . "<br />";
    }   
}else{
    echo "No playerid array found";
}
?>
```

This returns "No playerid array found".

If I remove the `if` statement check I get an "undefined index" error on `playerid`.

> Undefined index: playerid in C:\wamp64\www\projects\BowlsClub\displayTeams.php

Many thanks

Comment: Start by just setting a session variable on one page with the current time, and retrieving it on another, to see if sessions are working at all.

Comment: Check your PHP error log for "Headers already sent" errors.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_SESSION);` show on the 2nd page?

Comment: It just shows the array as empty with size 0

Comment: I did try sending a string as a session variable and that worked okay.

Comment: Can't find "Headers already sent" in the error log.

Comment: I don't know if there is a connection but I tried another approach by creating a table, filling the table with the id numbers, and checking it was filled,  then moving to the next page and then doing a 'select' on the table finding it was now empty. I tried it with another table in the db and found it worked ok. To me it defies logic unless there is some weird setting that I don't know about.

Comment: I've solved it, I was using $_POST to send the data to my first page then trying to pass it with session variable to the second page. I should have been posting it to the second page.  Thank you for your assistance.